# split data into separate values and assign them in span tags in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to separate a string which is joint by comma's and store it span tags separately so I can get the single value.
I am working in Vuejs with Php and getting the data from the database using Axios. I have a `product_color` value in the database join by comma's like this `Red,Black, White` and want to separate it just like PHP `explode()` function.
code below
Thanks and sorry for the poor English.

```
<div class="card p-5" v-for="(single, index) in singleProduct" :key="single.id">
     <h5 class="colors">colors:
      {{ single.product_color }}
      //getting value like this Red,Black,White
      <span class="color orange not-available" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
      <span class="color green"></span>
      <span class="color blue"></span>
      </h5>
</div>


import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'product-detail',
  data (){
    return {
       //data from api
       singleProduct: [],
       product_id: this.$route.params.product_id
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.fetchItem();
  },
  methods: {
    /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
        fetchItem(product_id) {
            axios
                .get(`http://localhost/vue/src/Api/api?action=fetchItem&product_id=${this.product_id}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
          this.singleProduct = res.data.product_data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        },
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help: [How to Explode a string in vue.js?](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-explode-a-string-in-vue-js/30974)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the js `split()` method on your string to create an array like php's `explode()`. Put it into a computed method to create the array and then add a v-for loop to output your spans:

```
data() {
    //your data attrs
},
computed: {
    productColors() {
        return this.singleProduct.product_color.split(',');
    }
},
```

and then in your template:

```
<span v-for="productColors as color" :class="'color '.color">{{color}}</span>
```

Comment: where should i put this line this.colorsArray = colorsString.split(',');  sorry i am newbie

Comment: @KashmiriAmmar Sorry, that was an old (and bad) example. Reload the page and you should see some better code.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_color' of undefined

Comment: @KashmiriAmmar Two things, I messed up the variable name - should be `return this.singleProduct.product_color`.... (single to singleProduct, and I updated the example above)

and you should be waiting to display your product until it's loaded. Add a check 

    <template v-if="singleProduct.length">
        [existing template]
    </template>